# How do I put a default string value into a hidden field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, default-value, form-for, hidden-field

I have a form that has one field which I need to submit a default string along with other information. The default string should not be editable, and I'd like it to be a hidden field so that no one can edit it when filling out the form, but can still submit it along with other visible form fields.

I have researched [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/how-can-i-set-default-value-for-text-field/154479/3) and [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) and followed their suggestions, but when I submit the form, the attribute is submitted as null.

Here is the form field:
`<%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'Reader' %>`

I'm expecting the column to populate with the term 'Reader' but it is empty.

Any suggestions on better ways to do this?

Comment: A hidden field is still editable to the clever and malicious user. Out of curiosity, why not just deal with this on the back end?

Comment: This is my first app in rails and if I’m being honest I’m not really sure how to do that yet. I’m not super concerned about a user altering this field, but I would like it to submit as the default that I set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%=f.hidden_field :role, :value => 'Reader', readonly: true%> or
<%=f.text_field :role, :value => 'Reader', readonly: true%>`

By giving " readonly: true " the value could not be editable in the form